# How to change JFXtras Agenda Skin?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jfxtras

I'm doing a timetable for a school project using JavaFX, I need to display the appointments in day and month skin but I don't know how to change the JFxtras Agenda Skin. I'm using JFxtras 8.0-r4.

Also, I want to change between weeks, days and months through a two buttons. If someone has any suggestion it would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call setSkin with a different skin implementation. But there also is an AgendaSkinSwitcher... How convenient :-)

https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/src/main/java/jfxtras/scene/control/agenda/AgendaSkinSwitcher.java

Comment: Thanks!!! It really helped me! But now I'm having a problem in adding the AgendaSkinSwitcher to the AnchorPane   :(

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at onestort.FXtrasAgController.initialize(FXtrasAgController.java:56)

       
 AnchorPane.getChildren().add(a);

Comment: Well, it seems something is not initialized (still null), but that has not much to do with JFXtras. You could place a few breakpoints to see if the code creating the objects is run before the code using them. The information above is certainly not enough to diagnose it.